# Rails Mongoid "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" on controller index and create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have just started using Mongoid for Rails and followed the screencast for it. I have generated a scaffold, have generated mongoid.yml, and changed only the database name. I have also followed the steps to prepare mongoid for rails in their documentation.

However, I always seem to be getting this on the create action

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Rails.root: /Users/ygamayatmiretuta/Documents/Dev/ruby/ta
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/notes_controller.rb:25:in `create'
```

and this one on the index action:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #12):

9:     <th></th>
10:   </tr>
11: 
12: <% @notes.each do |note| %>
13:   <tr>
14:     <td><%= note.title %></td>
15:     <td><%= note.description %></td>
```

Am I missing a config step or something? Thanks!

This is the controller:

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html

  def index
    @notes = Note.all.entries
    respond_with @notes
  end

  def show
    @notes = Note.find params[:id]
    respond_with @notes
  end

  def new
    @notes = Note.new
    respond_with @notes
  end

  def edit
    @notes = Note.find params[:id]
    respond_with @notes
  end

  def create
    @notes = Note.create params[:notes]
    respond_with @notes
  end

  def update
    @notes = Note.find params[:id]
    @notes.update_attributes params[:notes]
    respond_with @notes
  end

  def destroy
    @notes = Note.find params[:id]
    @notes.destroy
    respond_with @notes
  end
end
```

Comment: What are the steps you followed?
Can you post the Full Trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to Ruby 1.9.3 and that fixed the problems.

Comment: my guess is because you didn't accept the answer. I've given you the upvote in hopes that you accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here @tasks is nil. And you are trying to iterate it. Thats why this error is coming.

Comment: it is obviously nil but what causes it to be so? I mean, I have followed the steps, however, I can't create the record because it says'undefined method [] for NilClass' when I tried it in the console

Answer (score 0):

YOu need to upgrade to Ruby 1.9.3 see:

https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/2194